# Filter data with duplicate record in kendoTreeList

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-treelist

In KendoJqueryTreelist, when filter data using Contains then duplicate record is not show

In KendoJqueryTreelist, when filter data using Contains then duplicate record is not show, But i require to show all record that contains(Including duplicate record) in kendo jquery treelist. filter by last name

```
"<script>

  $("#treeList1").kendoTreeList({
    columns: [
      "lastName",
      "position"
    ],
    filterable: true,
    dataSource: {
      data: [
        { id: 1, parentId: null, lastName: "Jackson", position: "CEO" },
        { id: 2, parentId: 1, lastName: "Weber", position: "  VP, Engineering" },
        { id: 1, parentId: null, lastName: "Jackson", position: "CEO" },
        { id: 4, parentId: 1, lastName: "Weber", position: "  VP, Engineering" }
      ]
    }
  });


</script>"
```

Comment: Can you post one executable example?

Answer (score 0):

Telerik/Kendo never likes to have duplicate id's breaks almost all of their components, I would on the server side generate a unique id for every row and add a new column if "employee-id" is used:

```
$("#treeList1").kendoTreeList({
 columns: [
  "lastName",
  "position"
 ],
filterable: true,
dataSource: {
  data: [
    { id:1, employeeId: 1, parentId: null, lastName: "Jackson", position: "CEO" },
    { id:2, employeeId: 2, parentId: 1, lastName: "Weber", position: "  VP, Engineering" },
    { id:3, employeeId: 1, parentId: null, lastName: "Jackson", position: "CEO" },
    { id:4, employeeId: 4, parentId: 1, lastName: "Weber", position: "  VP, Engineering" }
  ]
}
});
</script>"
```